# What is the process for migrating a small database from Teradata to Db2?

Tags: db2, teradata

What is the process for migrating a small database from Teradata to Db2? And what challenges can one expect when doing this?

Comment: Question is too vague. Which DB2 hardware-platform and what number of terabytes are involved? So much depends on the SLAs for availability and recoverability.  The main challenge is inadequate planning and inexperienced project-staff.

Comment: You can use SAS for it, since it correctly translates the DDL metadata between the two.

Comment: I'm requesting that this question be closed as too broad for SO. I would agree with @access_granted about using an outside ETL tool to do the work for you. Short of that, dumping each table as CSV and importing into DB2 would be your other option, but that won't be fun.